# Rspec testing a controller using from to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Tested in browser and works fine. Test error says "expected result to have changed from 0 to 1, but did not change". Is this a factory issue or rspec issue? Why is it not changing?

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) ShortLinksController Short links controller Clicking a short link increments the click counter by 1
     Failure/Error: expect{ get :url_dispatch, { id: short_link.short_link } }.to change{short_link.click_counter}.from(0).to(1)
       expected result to have changed from 0 to 1, but did not change
     # ./spec/controllers/short_links_controller_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Rspec:

```
  it "increments the click counter by 1" do
    short_link = create(:short_link)
    expect{ get :url_dispatch, { id: short_link.short_link } }.to change{short_link.click_counter}.from(0).to(1)
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def url_dispatch
    id = params[:id]
    record = ShortLink.where(["short_link = ?", id]).first

    if record.update(click_counter: record.click_counter + 1)
      redirect_to record.redirect_to
    else
      render '/not_found'
    end
  end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :short_link do
    redirect_to "http://google.com"
    title "This is the google page"
    short_link "xGh7u"
    click_counter 0
    owner Owner.create!(first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Diller", email: "bdiller@example.com")
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's a `FactoryGirl` issue based on the fact that the same code works fine if you call the model instead of the factory.  I'm using `reload` to get around this for now in my controller tests but I'm curious if anyone has an answer.

Comment: Hey @Anthony thats interesting. I think its a FG issue too. Can you post your work around as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

per Fab's request, here is how I'm currently working around the issue.

```
context 'save invocations' do
  before(:each) do
    @org = create(:organization)
    user = create(:user, organization: @org, is_admin: true)
    sign_in user
  end
  it 'valid scenario' do
    user2 = create(:user, organization: @org, is_admin: false)
    put :update, id: user2, user: { is_admin: true }

    user2.reload
    expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    expect(user2.is_admin).to eq true
  end
end
```

Here I'm calling `user2.reload` in order to get the updated attributes from the user2 factory.

I don't know why the `expect{}` syntax doesn't work for factories but you could refactor your code like this:

```
  it "increments the click counter by 1" do
    short_link = create(:short_link)
    count = short_link.click_counter
    get :url_dispatch, { id: short_link.short_link }
    short_link.reload

    expect(short_link.click_counter).to eq count + 1
  end
```

Again I'm not saying this is best practice, I just couldn't find anything in the FactoryGirl documentation regarding RSpec 3 expect syntax in controllers that update attributes.

Comment: I tried to research this and from what I could find, I'm starting to believe that this is the proper implementation. Unless someone comes along and provides a better way. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds good - I'm curious if anyone from the `FactoryGirl` core team has any "better practices".